# Parsing shell commands in c: string cutting with respect to its contents

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm currently creating Linux shell to learn more about system calls.

I've already figured out most of the things. Parser, token generation, passing appropriate things to appropriate system calls - works.

The thing is, that even before I start making tokens, I split whole command string into separate words. It's based on array of separators, and it works surprisingly good. Except that I'm struggling with adding additional functionality to it, like escape sequences or quotes. I can't really live without it, since even people using basic grep commands use arguments with quotes. I'll need to add functionality for:

- `' '` - ignore every other separator, operator or double quotes found between those two, pass this as one string, don't include these quotation marks into resulting word,
- `" "`- same as above, but ignore single quotes,
- `\\` - escape this into single backslash,
- `\(space)` - escape this into space, do not parse resulting space as separator
- `\"`, `\'` - analogously to the above.
- Many other things that I haven't figured out I need yet

and every single one of them seems like an exception on its own. Each of them must operate on diversity of possible positions in commands, being included into result or not, having influence on the rest of the parsing. It makes my code look like big ball of mud.

Is there a better approach to do this? Is there a more general algorithm for that purpose?

Comment: Why not use Lex/Yacc - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29?

Comment: @EdHeal I'll try that for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve a classic problem in program analysis (of lexing and parsing) using a nontraditional structure for lexer ( *I split whole command string into separate words...* ).   OK, then you will have non-traditional troubles with getting the lexer "right".

That doesn't mean  that way is doomed to failure, and without seeing specific instances of your problem, (you list a set of constructs you want to handle, but don't say why these are hard to process), it is hard to provide any specific advice.  It also doesn't mean that way will lead to success; splitting the line may break tokens that shouldn't be broken (usually by getting confused about what has been escaped).

The point of using a standard lexer (such as Flex or [any of the 1000 variants you can get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators)) is that they provide a *proven* approach to complex lexing problems, based generally on the idea that one can use regular expressions to describe the shape of individual lexemes.  Thus, you get one regexp per lexeme type, thus an ocean of them but each one is pretty easy to specify by itself.

I've done ~~40 languages using strong lexers and parsers (using one of the ones in that list).  I assure you the standard approach is empirically pretty effective.  The types of surprises are well understood and manageable.   A nonstandard approach always has the risk that it will surprise you in a bad way.

Last remark: shell languages for Unix have had people adding crazy stuff for 40 years.  Expect the job to be at least medium hard, and don't expect it to be pretty like Wirth's original Pascal.

Comment: I actually started that project because I hate bash's quirky syntax. Specifically after I tried to +=1 a variable, which produced "11" instead of 2, and made me a little bit more balding than I was before.

The troubles I'm facing with each of the position on my list is that their behavior changes depending on where they are in the string. Considering something like this: `com\ 1"something" |com2 arg1 arg\ 2 "arg '3' \ "`. Each of the `"`, `'`, `\ ` provide different exception case in my code. And it's just irritating.

Comment: It seems to me that the "+1 a variable produces 11" isn't a syntax problem; its a disagreement about what the semantics of "+=" should be (add one to a variable no matter what?  append a character to a variable if it is a string?).  With a standard tool, you might not like its semantics but you pretty much have to live with them unless you want to rewrite it yourself (oh, wait, you're do that :)

Comment: Of the specific troubles you list, many are resolvable in a classic lexer by processing then in the context in which they are found; escapes especially.    Escapes are normally picked up as part of scanning particular lexemes and can thus be processed knowing they are such.

Comment: I don't like living with things that are making my live harder. Bash's quirkyness when it comes to it's operators and "intuitiveness" is one of them. So yea, I'm rewriting :P.

Comment: What you are likely to discover is that you can rewrite it yourself (with a lot of effort) but other lazy people will still continue to use the already-existing, widely available version.  You'll get no traction and life is hard enough without replacing everything with a shiny version before you get on with your real work.  Having said that, progress is made by the unreasonable man; more power to you, and you will learn a lot.  Enjoy.